# c# showing error while browsing a webpage

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium

This is a test program. I just created a simple Windows application form with one button, and if the button is clicked, I need it to do something. So, I wrote my code as:

```
IWebDriver driver;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetupTest()
    {            
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }    
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("webaddress");
        driver.FindElement(By.TagName("Atlast")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

I have included all of the dependencies (both code and references), but I am getting the following error when I click the button:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in driver.navigate part of my code..
```

What mistake did I make here? Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: please show us your code where the exception is happening.  Not the driver code, the buttonClick code.  That exception means that you tried to use a variable before assigning a value to it

Comment: Well debug it - is `driver` null? What other code are you using? Where do you create your instance of your `WebDriver`?

Comment: @RussellUhl;@Arran:

Please see my edit on question..

Comment: Two things I notice here.  First, driver is not static, so if a new instance of the enclosing class is ever created, driver will have to be re-initialized.  Second, and I say this because I'm not sure how the internal mechanics of windows forms work (I only use C# with aspx code), you may have to call `SetupTest()` (or more specifically, re-instantiate `driver`) every time the buttonclick gets called.  While this may not be optimal, give it a try to see if that fixes the issue.  The problem is that for whatever reason, `driver` is null at the entry point of the buttonclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetupTest()
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("webaddress");
    driver.FindElement(By.TagName("Atlast")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

You need to be calling `SetupTest` in your button click code. Why? This is where you are creating your new instance of the `IWebDriver`, therefore it needs to be called otherwise any references to `driver` will simply refer to `null` (by default).